# IHTMLDocument2.write() memoryleak

Tags: mfc

In MFC CDHtmlDialog, I am updating HTML content using IHTMLDocument2's write function.

My Dialog is a modelless dialog. I am using same dialog object throughout the application.

Everytime I write something to the embedded browser, and look at memory
usage in task manager, the used memory seems to go up by about 750 KB per
IHTMLDocument2::write/close. If I comment out the call to
m_spHtmlDoc->write(pSA);  the memory usage is more normal.

I am using below code to update the HTML Content.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CEzHtmlChildDlg, CDHtmlDialog)

CEzHtmlChildDlg::CEzHtmlChildDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDHtmlDialog(CEzHtmlChildDlg::IDD, 0, pParent)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::Create(CEzHtmlChildDlg::IDD, pParent);
}

CEzHtmlChildDlg::~CEzHtmlChildDlg()
{
}

void CEzHtmlChildDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BOOL CEzHtmlChildDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    SetHostFlags(m_dwHostFlags
        | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIALOG                  // MSHTML does not enable selection of the text in the form
        | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_HELP_MENU       // MSHTML does not add the Help menu item to the container's menu.
        | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO               // MSHTML does not have scroll bars.
        | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE // MSHTML does not execute any script until fully activated.
        | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME                   // Specifies that the hosted browser should use themes for pages it displays
//      | DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NOTHEME
        );

    CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // disable drop targets
    // Don't allow user to drop shortcut onto this window and have the browser
    // navigate to show that web site
    m_pBrowserApp->put_RegisterAsDropTarget(VARIANT_FALSE);



    EnableAutomation();
    LPDISPATCH pDisp = GetIDispatch(FALSE);
    SetExternalDispatch(pDisp);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

BOOL CEzHtmlChildDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && 
        (pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE || pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN || pMsg->wParam == VK_F5))
        return true;

    if (pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
        return TRUE;

    return CDHtmlDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEzHtmlChildDlg, CDHtmlDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_DHTML_EVENT_MAP(CEzHtmlChildDlg)

END_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()

// CEzHtmlChildDlg message handlers

void CEzHtmlChildDlg::SetHTML(CString strHtml)
{
    // Create a safearray to store the HTML text
    SAFEARRAY      *pSA;
    SAFEARRAYBOUND  saBound = {1, 0};
    pSA = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, &saBound);

     CComVariant varDummy;

    // Copy the HTML into the one and only element
    VARIANT   *pVar;
    CComBSTR   bstrHTML = strHtml;              // Load the text
    varDummy = bstrHTML;                        // .. into a variant

    SafeArrayAccessData(pSA, (void**)&pVar);    // Access safearray data
    pVar[0] = varDummy;                         // Set the text data
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(pSA);                 // Release access

     // Write the HTML as the document's new text
    m_spHtmlDoc->write(pSA);                           // Overwrite HTML
    m_spHtmlDoc->close();                              // Update browser

    SafeArrayDestroy(pSA);                      // Finished with the safearray
}
```

m_spHtmlDoc  is a member variable of CDhtmlDialog.

What is the mistake I am doing while writing to document?,

Comment: My guess is you have to do `m_spHtmlDoc->Release();`

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/195b68b5-958f-48b3-abd1-bbe3aacaca48/ihtmldocument2write-memoryleak?forum=vcgeneral